# Uploading series of OS map sheets using QGIS and merging together?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I need to upload historic OS sheets in tiff format, and 'stitch' them together, as some districts are spread over a number of sheets.

I have no idea how to do this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Georeferencing the maps http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html Mosaic (merge) http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/raster_mosaicing_and_clipping.html

Answer (score 1):

I'll try and answer your first question.

If you have academic access to OS historical mapping I think the sheets you downloaded will already be georeferenced. That is, for each TIFF file there will be a TFW file that contains geoferencing data. The TIFFs and the TFWs must be kept together in the same directory.

Assuming the sheets are georeferenced, the easiest way of 'merging' them will probably be to create virtual raster, a VRT file. To do this, in the menu at the top of the screen click on 'Raster'. Go down to 'Miscellaneous' and then across to  'Build Virtual Raster(Catalog)'. In the window that pops up select the files you wish to merge, and provide a name for the output VRT file. Then press 'OK'.

If everything works as it should your 'merged' TIFFs should now appear on the QGIS screen.

Now, most important. The rules here are that you're only allowed to ask one question at a time, so what I'd suggest you do is start another thread for your question about the data, and delete your Question 2 above. In the new thread make sure you describe the format and structure of the data you have.

***Added later:*** From your comments it appears that this answer didn't work. It might be worth converting your TIFFs to GeoTIFFs which you can do as follows.

Click on 'Raster' go down to 'Projections' and then right to 'Warp (Reproject). In the window that appears select the input file and provide a file name and location for the output file. Leave all of the tick boxes unticked and press 'OK'. Do this for two of your raster images to see if they align properly in QGIS. If they do convert the rest and then 'merge' them by making a VRT as outlined above.

I hope this works, I know that QGIS/GDAL has problems with some MapInfo TAB files, something to do with rotation and shear if I remember rightly. N.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - very helpful. Apologies for the two questions - I wasn't aware of the one question rule. I tried your approach to creating a virtual raster, but it didn't work. The folder with the .tiff images has associated .tab images. When I try selecting the .tiff files as input files I get the error message: 'ASCII value for tag "ImageDescription" contains null byte in value; [...] does not support ungeoreferenced image.' If I select the .tab files it tells me that they are unsupported. Are .tabs not the same as .tfws?

Comment: TABs are the MapInfo equivalent of TFWs and QGIS should be able to use them, I wonder why not in your case. If you load two of your (abutting) TIFFs into QGIS do they align properly?

Comment: I've tried loading two abutting TIFFs but had the same response - they wouldn't upload. Any ideas? I also have access to DIVA GIS, if you know a way creating a VRT using that? Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: Okay, make sure the TAB file is in the same directory as the TIFF and them load the TIFF into QGIS. Do the coordinates reported for the cursor as you move it round the screen make sense as OS coordinates? (eg. nnnnnn,nnnnnn.)

Comment: That said, I have come across problems with TAB files, historic OS TIFFs and QGIS before. If yours is the same problem there is a way around it, but let me know if you get sensible coordinates first.

Comment: The TAB files are in the same folder as the TIFFs. When I load in a TIFF as a raster layer, the co-ordinates change and seem to make sense as I move the cursor around. On another note, I tried georeferencing a sheet as instructed here (http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html) which ended up inverting my map and turning it 90 degrees.

Comment: Another thing: the quality of the OS sheet diminsihes when I load it into QGIS.

Comment: I think the problem is that QGIS can't interpret the TABs properly. I'll add a possible way round this to my answer.